# Field not found: 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.DeleteCommand'

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

On a client machine, I received this error. Can someone suggest me what can be the possible issue?

Here is the complete stack trace of the issue:

```
Error Message
Field not found: 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.DeleteCommand'.
Stack Trace 
  at ABC.MyNameSpace.DataGridGridUserControl.OnCanExecuteDelete(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
 at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecuteWrapper(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CanExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
       at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecute(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
       at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CanExecute(Object parameter, IInputElement target)
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CanExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.UpdateCanExecute()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.HookCommand(ICommand command)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnCommandChanged(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, Boolean isDetach, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, ParserContext parserContext, OptimizedTemplateContent optimizedTemplateContent, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
       at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
       at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
       at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
```

This is a WPF desktop application and we're using WPFToolkit June 2009. I suspect that wpf toolkit is not properly installed on client machine during installation and because of which datagrid's delete command is not found. Can someone help me with a workaround of this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: are you installing this first time or reinstalling with upgrades

Comment: We do provide latest product release but with each release older version of app is removed and new is installed. Not something like plug in. Also the issue is not with installation but while working on something on GUI (where data grid is used) app crashes.

Comment: Have you installed this on another systems and found same error or not. If you get same error then may be possible the error in your assembly. Then check the source code and files.

Comment: No this issue is happening only on a specific customer. Around thousand app installation are running successfully with no such error.

Comment: Have you checked the software or frameworks on that system which are necessary to run your application properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen when something is changed the assembly and create a or even worse rename a .ddl file. I suggest you to download the [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (is free to try) and inspect the .dll files.

Comment: Application is installed on client machine so there is no source code over there. Do you mean that someone deliberately changed some dll in program files where application is installed? If this is the case then I think application won't even start. Isn't it?

Comment: I cannot ensure that was deliberately, but for sure this what was happend .. and of course if is missing a .ddl file the system is unable to detect it.

Comment: Alright, I'll talk to customer and will try to have a remote on his system. Repair the existing framework.

Comment: Thanks Voislav Sauca, reinstalling the .net framework fixed this issue. :)